# WooCommerce как обновить цену

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Мне нужно обновить значения цены, на те, которые указаны в моём плагине. Как это сделать? update_option() уже пробовал не работает.

Comment: update_post_meta

Comment: это тоже пробовал

Comment: Что именно вы пробовали? что не получилось? ибо вышеуказанной функцией - можно обновить цену, но только ее для этого не хватит.
Приведите ваш пример(нерабочий?) - чтоб можно было понять что вы делаете не так.

Comment: писал так update_post_meta(переменная указывающая id, $product->get_price(), новое значение);

Comment: Ты смотрел что у тебя в передаваемых аргументах и что ожидает фунция?

Comment: Можете подсказать как правильно?

Comment: Вторым аргументом должен передаваться ключ поля, а не текущее значение

Comment: Что значит Ключ???

Comment: Ключ - это такое имя, по которому можно обратиться к полю

Comment: И как его можно узнать?

Comment: Распечатать все произвольные поля текущего товара `print_r(get_post_meta($post_id))` и посмотреть

Comment: а не проще загуглить как обновить цену? Зачем спрашивать одно и тоже?